# Creating a bottom border of element(s) on top of a "row" with bottom border

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a varying number of items that may or may not fit in a single "row", inside a container. If they don't fit, another "row(s)" should be created.

All items will contain a single word (or 2 max), so no more than 1 line of data. Each item should have a bottom border of 1px, and each row should also have a bottom border of 1px, so the result would look like this:

```
|-----------------------------------
|                                  |
|  Foo bar    Foo bar      Foo bar |
|--=======-------------------------|
|                                  |
|                                  |
|  Foo bar    Foo bar      Foo bar |
|----------------------------------|
```

(Mouse is hovering the first item).

The bottom border of the items should appear on top of the line at the bottom of the row (hiding as much of the row border as the width of the item is).

I have [this codepen](http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/XbyXwa?editors=110), but

- I have no idea how to style the bottom border of each "row"
- The items are moving every time I place the mouse on top of one of them.

What should I use to achieve what I want?

**Note:** I can use CSS3 if that will make it easier.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 2px 7px 2px 7px;
}

.item:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will all the elements always have only one line of text? If yes, your probably don't need a markup change.

Comment: @Harry, yes, all items will contain a single word (or 2 max), so no more than 1 line.

Comment: @Pete I placed the code here too, but the renderer is buggy. It's not rendering the border line of the container correctly.

Comment: @alexandernst  just need the code here as this is a reference site and intended to help people.  If the link breaks, then this won't be helpful in future if the code is not within the question

Comment: @alexandernst: How about [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/aOQNmK?editors=110)?

Comment: @Harry This is almost perfect! Only two things. 1) Can the red line appear on top of the blue line (hiding as much of the blue line as the width of the red line is) and 2) can you explain how this works?

Comment: @alexandernst: The border of container was not coming because the bootstrap CSS file which was included in CodePen wasn't included here (I assume it is a clearfix problem). I have added that and also the clarifications that were provided in comments into the question.

Comment: @alexandernst: I have added the linear-gradients tag to this question as the tag + approach could be useful for others in future. Please feel free to roll back if you think otherwise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents are always going to be max one line, you can set the `height` of each item to a fixed height (say `height: 2em`) and then use `linear-gradient` background for the parent container of the same height to produce a row line like effect. As you can see in the second block in the snippet, the lines are the parent's `background` and they are produced even if there is no content. This gives an illusion of the individual items having a full width bottom border.

This doesn't need any changes to your markup but do note that this approach would work fine only as long as the item's contents fit within a single line.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* following code produces the blue lines */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1.95em, blue 1.95em);
  background-size: 100% 2em;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position: 0px 0px; /* y position is dependant on border-top-width */
}
.item {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* to make padding part of element's height & width */
  float: left;
  height: 2em; /* a fixed height */
  padding: 2px 7px 2px 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; /* needed to avoid jumping */
}
.item:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red; /* red line that is shown on hover */
}

/* just for demo */

.demo{
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-position: 0px 1px;
  height: 8em;
}
.container:hover{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Foo bar long</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
  <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
</div>

<div class="container demo">

</div>
```

**Output Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Ok, I spotted one more bug. There is a blue line on top of the first row (shouldn't be there) and there is no blue line at the bottom of the last row (should be there).

Comment: @alexandernst: Sorry, I can't see anything like that. There is a line at the bottom of the last row and none on top of the first row. Can you let me know the browser and its version?

Comment: The bug appears as soon as I remove the grey border of the container.

Comment: @alexandernst: Oh ok, that is because you need to change the `background-position` to `0px 0px` when you remove the border of the container.

Comment: Perfect! One last thing. That solution assumes that the height of the text of each item is 2em, right? If so, is there a way to make it get the height of the text "automatically" so it will adjust by it's own if/when I change the text's font size?

Comment: @alexandernst: I had used `em` just because the `font-size` may change :)

Comment: Yup, but that is exactly what I'm asking. For example, if I set `font-size: 28px;` to the `.item` class, this stops working properly.

Comment: @alexandernst: If there are way too many constraints then you have no option but to use JS. If you could live with setting `font-size` on container then there would not be any issues due to change of values. Hover on the box in the snippet to see how `font-size` doesn't affect it.

Comment: True! I can set the font size in the container class. That works perfectly, thank you and kudos for the great solution!

Answer (score 0):

update your css with this.

```
.item {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 7px 2px 7px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that fixes the moving items problem, but what about the bottom border of each row?

Comment: Not, it's not. The bottom border of each element now shows correctly. They also don't move. So far, so good. What's missing is the bottom border of each row. Meaning, there should be a tiny 1px line from side to side under every row of elements (in this example, under each 3 "Foo bar"s).

Comment: you want to get border for entire first row when mouse overing any div...?

Comment: @alexandernst you can't. You haven't rows. You have divs child without separators. If you have `<tr>` you can, but with your html you need to use javascript to know what row are you hovering.

Comment: No, I want a bottom border showing up all the time (hovered or not). @MarcosPérezGude I was afraid of that, but I'm open to markup changes.

Comment: yah @MarcosPérezGude is correct if you have table structure then we can get entire row bottom. otherwise you need to wrap the divs in parent divs.

Comment: See my answer, you need a different markup, not neccessary `<table>`. But if you emulates the rows you can make it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your html to agrouped elements:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
       <div class="item">Foo bar</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can styling:

```
 .row:hover .item {
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
 }
```

SEE this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1LLzr8q7/

Comment: I can't do that markup as I don't know how many elements will fit in a row. Your code assumes that only 4 elements will fit, but this may not be the case.

Comment: Ok, then that you need is impossible to do. You need to calculate very complex formulas in javascript to achieve it. If you don't know how many elements by row you need, you can't paint the elements of one row because you don't have rows. What if you have a row with 4 elements and then a row with 6?